# Non-unique id of DOM elements in Handlebars templates

Tags: html, templates, dom, handlebars.js, uniqueidentifier

I want to know if it is allowed to have several *Handlebars* templates on the same html page when each of them contain non-unique ids? Depending on the circumstances **only one template at a time** will be compiled and loaded into the DOM.

Or asking differently, are the html elements inside the `<script>` tags part of the DOM tree and also must have unique id values?

There's a snippet (the end) of my html/*Handlebars*, you can see two templates each of them contain elements with *obj-id* and *obj-name* id attribute values.

```
<script id="task-details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="obj-name">Task name</label>
        <input type="text" id="obj-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="obj-id">Task ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="obj-id">
    </div>
</script>

<script id="operator-details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="obj-name">Operator name</label>
        <input type="text" id="obj-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="obj-id">Operator code</label>
        <input type="text" id="obj-id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="obj-age">Operator age</label>
        <input type="text" id="obj-age">
    </div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To form valid HTML5:

> [The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

That said, your website will not "crash". You can check this fiddle to see that the website still works: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariotacke/mwheofp6/)

You could instead declare a common class name which would more closely follow the spec, OR use Handlebars to populate the id fields by binding an object to the template when you need it. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="{{id-from-an-object-you-bind-to-the-template}}">
```

Comment: Thank you, Mario. Maybe I've formulated my question vaguely or I don't fully understand your answer. I was interesting if templates, having non-unique ids, can exist in the same document. Now I've tested that with a simple javascript. It seems that the html elements between the `<script></script>` tags don't participate in the document object model. At least DOM methods `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` don't find them. So, I think templates with non-unique id may exist on the page.